# Cygnus does not reconnect to kafka broker

Tags: fiware-cygnus

I am using cygnus-kafka connector. when the connection is lost beetween cygnus and the zookeeper. cygnus can not reconnect again to the zookeeper when the conenction is back. I need to restart it so it will be able to reconnect to the zookeeper.

Any ideas why cygnus is not able to reconnect to the kafka broker if the connection was lost once?

This the error that I got:

```
time=2016-11-30T11:29:26.254Z | lvl=WARN | corr=2a924ba4-b6f0-11e6-8836-fa163e68f7a2 | trans=ce766745-ae85-415a-a6f3-0bed9f121e79 | srv=service| subsrv=/servicepath | function=run | comp=cygnusagent | msg=org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread[1185] : Session 0x0 for server kafkaServerIp/kafkaServerIp:2181, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.doIO(ClientCnxn.java:856)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1154)
time=2016-11-30T11:29:28.211Z | lvl=WARN | corr=2a924ba4-b6f0-11e6-8836-fa163e68f7a2 | trans=ce766745-ae85-415a-a6f3-0bed9f121e79 | srv=service| subsrv=/servicepath | function=processNewBatches | comp=cygnusagent | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink[439] : Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 10000
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the connection from Cygnus to Kafka is permanent, because of efficiency issues. Nevertheless, a check for reseted connection by peer is missing in the code. I'll fix it ASAP in order it is ready for next version release (1.7.0) by the end of January (of course, it will be available at `master` branch once fixed, much sooner).

Comment: Related issue in Github: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/issues/1346